# Is there a way to send an email in Powershell with a button?

Tags: powershell

I need to send an email using powershell that will send a button that runs a batch command once the user clicks on it.
The batch command is a simple curl command that triggers a job on a jenkins server.
I prefer to hide the text behind the curl command and just give a button to click on or a link if possible.

Is that possible in Powershell ? if so how can i do it ?

Comment: Well Abbey, you may look into `Send-MailMessage`. As far as your request lol can you rephrase what you're asking? Currently doesnt make sense to me. Mail filters block .bat files if thats what you're referring to.

Comment: so basically i send and email , and in the email body is a button that may say "Upload File" , the button has some batch code attached to it  and when the user clicks on the button , in the background the batch command will be run

Comment: Don't think it's easy to do with .bat files. Macros you probably could but, that's a different beast as well!

Comment: What you are asking is generally not allowed. You see, back on the days crackers were sending emails left and right with pretext of "click here to see funny cat video or $celebirty naked" And people did click, oh, they did! The embedded programs didn't contain entertainment, but malware. Nowadays you'd get a cryptocurrency miner in the best case, ransomware in the worst. So, executing attachments is made hard on purpose. Please [edit] the question and explain the bigger picture of what you are trying to achieve. There likely is a way, but more details about the workflow would be helpful.

Comment: question has been expanded on.

Comment: Just save the batch file on a server shared folder and send them a link to where it is for them to double click it.